# avoid multiple returns looped in javascript - async / await to solve callback pyramid or callback hell,

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

I have this code, with a lot of blocks of returns, by example SignUp()

connectors.js

```
  const connectors = {
      Auth: {
        signUp(args) {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // Validate the data
            if (!args.email) {
              return reject({
                code: 'email.empty',
                message: 'Email is empty.'
              });
            } else if (!isEmail(args.email)) {
              return reject({
                code: 'email.invalid',
                message: 'You have to provide a valid email.'
              });
            }

            if (!args.password) {
              return reject({
                code: 'password.empty',
                message: 'You have to provide a password.'
              });
            }

            return encryptPassword(args.password, (err, hash) => {
              if (err) {
                return reject(new Error('The password could not be hashed.'));
              }

              return User.create(Object.assign(args, { password: hash }))
                .then((user) => {
                  resolve(createToken({ id: user._id, email: user.email }));
                })
                .catch((err2) => {
                  if (err2.code === 11000) {
                    return reject({
                      code: 'user.exists',
                      message: 'There is already a user with this email.'
                    });
                  }

                  return reject(err2);
                });
            });
          });
        },
    };

    module.exports = connectors;
```

then anoter code that call this code:

```
 const connectors = require('./connectors');

   CallsignUp(root, args) {
      const errors = [];

      return connectors.Auth.signUp(args)
        .then(token => ({
          token,
          errors
        }))
        .catch((err) => {
          if (err.code && err.message) {
            errors.push({
              key: err.code,
              value: err.message
            });
            return { token: null, errors };
          }

          throw new Error(err);
        });
    }
```

how it's possible to avoid this in ES6 or ES7 or ES2017?

there are:

```
  return()
   .then()
     return()
       .then
```

and just loop returns:

```
return()
   return()
       return()
```

comming from PHP this code looks crazy, because return functions that return functions, and it's not clear for me, how is the name in javascript this type of block return code? calling functions that returns again more code?

**UPDATED:**

Code is not mine, full source in

https://github.com/jferrettiboke/react-auth-app-example

I'd like to understand by example:

```
    return encryptPassword(args.password, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(new Error('The password could not be hashed.'));
      }

      return User.create(Object.assign(args, { password: hash }))
        .then((user) => {
        .catch((err2) => {

          return reject(err2);
```

/src/utils/auth.js (here is encryptPassword)

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const config = require('../config');
exports.encryptPassword = (password, callback) => {
  // Generate a salt then run callback
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) { return callback(err); }

    // Hash (encrypt) our password using the salt
    return bcrypt.hash(password, salt, null, (err2, hash) => {
      if (err2) { return callback(err2); }
      return callback(null, hash);
    });
  });
};
```

there are 3 returns calling functions and returning values and functions? OOP is never like this, how to use Async/Await suggest by @dashmud, i don't want to learn old things like callbacks

Comment: *"return functions that return functions"* - When you say `return reject(...)` that calls the `reject()` function immediately and then returns whatever *its* return value is. That's pretty normal in almost all modern languages, and isn't the same thing as returning a function.

Comment: Welcome to functional programming -- something PHP is terrible at.

Comment: By the way, I just noticed some naming that made me a little concerned. It appears you have a function called `encryptPassword()` that is actually hashing it instead. Encrypting is not the same thing as hashing, and this isn't just semantics, that's kind of a huge security concern for storing sensitive data. Make sure that your password is actually _hashed_, which is a one-way function without a key, rather than encrypting, which is a two-way function with a key, and name your function as such, like `hashPassword()`.

Comment: please read the update in my question, the code is not mine, i'm just try understand the code and looking for to update to es7, callback , about security and anothers reason is not important on the question

Comment: FYI, `async/await` is part of ES2017 (this year's release), not ES7 (ES2016, last years release).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending [@jfriend00's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46167254/1541563), here's an approach that uses the [ES2017 `async` / `await`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/2017/#sec-async-function-definitions) syntax to flatten the [callback pyramid](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/215327/dealing-with-the-node-js-callback-pyramid) or [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/), however you prefer to call it:

```
const encryptPasswordPromise = require('util').promisify(encryptPassword)

const connectors = {
  Auth: {
    async signUp (args) {
      const { email, password } = args
      // Validate the data
      let err

      if (!email) {
        err = { code: 'email.empty', message: 'Email is empty.' }
      } else if (!isEmail(email)) {
        err = { code: 'email.invalid', message: 'You have to provide a valid email.' }
      } else if (!password) {
        err = { code: 'password.empty', message: 'You have to provide a password.' }
      }

      if (err) {
        throw err
      }

      let hash

      try {
        hash = await encryptPasswordPromise(password)
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error('The password could not be hashed.')
      }

      const { _id: id, email } = await User.create(Object.assign(args, { password: hash }))

      try {
        return createToken({ id, email })
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.code === 11000) {
          throw { code: 'user.exists', message: 'There is already a user with this email.' }
        } else {
          throw err
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

module.exports = connectors
```

Rather than handwrite my own promisified promise-based `encryptPassword()`, I opted to use a node.js builtin transformation function for that called [`util.promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

Overall, there are still a few improvements that could be made like moving the validation of the `signUp()` arguments to a separate function, but none of that is related to flattening the "callback hell" anti-pattern that gave rise to promise-based control-flow and async/await syntax.

Comment: You don't believe in semi-colons?

Comment: @jfriend00 I've recently (early this year) adopted this style, which I find agreeable: https://standardjs.com/. I realize this is not an officially endorsed standard or anything like that, it's just the way I prefer to write now.

Comment: It really throws the eye off for someone used to the pattern recognition of semi-colons at the end of statements.  Makes it harder for a seasoned veteran to immediately read the code.  I put them in because I've been bitten by strange edge cases when they are missing and it can make really puzzling bugs (errors reported many lines away from the actual error).  I'd much rather let a minimizer remove them for browser code and leave them in for node.js code.  But, to each his own, I guess.

Comment: I've never had errors appear on wrong lines, personally, and since `standard` comes with its own linter, my `npm publish` literally prevents me from committing code that potentially has bugs due to automatic semicolon insertion, so that's never an issue for me anyway.

Comment: `async/await` is part of ES2017, not ES7 (ES2016).

Comment: @FelixKling ah, it appears you are correct. Thank you for pointing that out, it's corrected now.

Comment: @DDave I appreciate you marking this as correct, but if you like this answer, I'd actually feel more comfortable with you accepting jfriend00's answer since he put in most of the work in explaining what's going on. My code is literally the async/await equivalent of his code.

Answer (score 4):

This code needs to be refactored in a number of ways.  First, you really, really don't want to mix promises and plain async callbacks in the same logic flow.  It makes a mess and wrecks a lot of the advantages of promises.  Then, you have an anti-pattern going using promises inside of `new Promise()`.  Then, you have more nesting that is required (you can chain instead).

Here's what I'd suggest:

```
function encryptPasswordPromise(pwd) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        encryptPassword(pwd, (err, hash) => {
            err ? reject(new Error("The password could not be hashed.")) : resolve(hash);
        });
    });
}

const connectors = {
    Auth: {
        signUp(args) {
            // Validate the data
            let err;
            if (!args.email) {
                err = {code: 'email.empty', message: 'Email is empty.'};
            } else if (!isEmail(args.email)) {
                err = {code: 'email.invalid', message: 'You have to provide a valid email.'};
            } else if (!args.password) {
                err = {code: 'password.empty', message: 'You have to provide a password.'};
            }
            if (err) {
                return Promise.reject(err);
            } else {
                return encryptPasswordPromise(args.password).then(hash => {
                    args.password = hash;
                    return User.create(args);
                }).then((user) => {
                    return createToken({id: user._id, email: user.email});
                }).catch(err2 => {
                    if (err2.code === 11000) {
                        throw new Error({code: 'user.exists', message: 'There is already a user with this email.'});
                    } else {
                        throw err2;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Summary of Changes:

1. Collect all errors initially and do return `Promise.reject(err)` in one place for all those initial errors.
2. Promisify `encryptPassword()` so you aren't mixing regular callbacks with promise logic flow and you can then properly return and propagate errors.
3. Removing wrapping of the whole code with `return new Promise()` since all your async operations are now promisified so you can just return promises directly.  This really helps with proper error handling too.
4. Undo unneccessary nesting and just chain instead.
5. Remove `Object.assign()` as there did not appear to be a reason for it.

---

In your edit, you asked for an explanation of this code segment:

```
return encryptPassword(args.password, (err, hash) => {
  if (err) {
    return reject(new Error('The password could not be hashed.'));
  }

  return User.create(Object.assign(args, { password: hash }))
    .then((user) => {
    .catch((err2) => {

      return reject(err2);
```

1. This code calls `encryptPassword()`.
2. It returns the result of that which is probably `undefined` so all the `return` is doing is controlling program flow (exiting the containing function), but since there is no code after that return at the same level, that's unnecessary.
3. You pass a callback to `encryptPassword()`.  That callback is asynchronous, meaning it is called some time later.
4. The callback gets two arguments: `err` and `hash`.  In the node.js async calling convention, if the first argument is truthy (e.g. contains some truthy value), then it represents an error.  If it is falsey (usually `null`), then there is no error and the second argument contains the result of the asynchronous operation.
5. If there was an error, the parent promise is rejected and the callback is exited.  Again, there is no return value from `reject` so the `return` is just for exiting the callback at that point (so no other code in the callback runs).
6. Then, another asynchronous operation `User.create()` is called and it is passed the args object with a new password set in it.
7. `User.create()` returns a promise so its result is captured with a `.then()` method and a callback passed to that.
8. Some time later, when the asynchronous `User.create()` finishes, it will resolve its promise and that will cause the `.then()` callback to get called and the result will be passed to it.  If there's an error in that operation, then the `.then()` callback will not be called, instead the `.catch()` callback will be called.  In that `.catch()` callback, the parent promise is rejected.  This is a promise anti-pattern (resolving a parent promise inside another promise) because it is very easy to make mistakes in proper error handling.  My answer shows how to avoid that.

Comment: Mind if I extend your code to provide an ES7 answer, or are you already working on that?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - I'd be happy for you to extend with an ES7 version.

Comment: please read the update in my question, the code is not mine, i'm just try understand the code and looking for to update to es7, callback and promises make me crazy

Comment: @DDave - You need to learn how promises work.  Plain and simple.  You can't use async/await until you know how promises work and you can't use promises until you understand async operations and async callbacks.  There's no skipping to the front of the line without learning.  I'll add something to my answer that explains that particular code segment.  But, what my answer is showing you is a CLEAN and significantly simpler way to write that code.  You should attempt to understand that too.

Comment: @jfriend00 , code is not mine, i know simple   promises, callbacks because i was working a little bit with node, express, and angular , but looking this full code , it's confused. i'd like to learn es7 inside

Comment: @DDave - I added an explanation of this code.  You can learn ES7 just fine, but if you attempt to use `async/await` without understanding how promises work, you will be hopelessly confused and write bad code.  I've seen LOTS of beginners march off to ES7 and write synchronous looking code for async operations and they make horrible mistakes with error handling and control flow because it isn't really synchronous code.  It's async code and you have to understand how it works to write good code, even ES7 code.

Comment: @DDave  -   `async/await` is syntactical sugar for `promise.then()`.  It's convenient to use it (saves some typing) once you understand how `promise.then()` works and how promise chaining and nesting works and how errors propagate in promises, but it's not a replacement for any of those.  I've been predicting a wave of pretty bad async code written in ES7 syntax because it lets you write bad code really quickly.  One can also write good code quicker than before, but not without proper understandings of async and errors.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, hope you find my extension of your code to be agreeable.

Comment: @jfriend00 i've studied your code, thanks your efforts, just a last question , encryptPassword() give you a promise ? why did you change the name to encryptPasswordPromise()? in my question there is the original code for the function, thanks again

Comment: @DDave - I changed the name because the source for that function was not present in your original question (or at least I didn't see it) so I had no idea if it was something you could just edit or if there was other code using it the way it was.  If you own that function, but all means just edit it to return a promise.

Comment: I voted for this answer. It's a great explanation. Looking at the OP's comments, it proved my point in my answer that understanding callbacks, promises, is essential before doing `async/await`.

Comment: @jfriend00 your response is very good to understand the actual code, but i had to choose the another one because my final goals was to convert the code in ES2017 and I can't choose 2 answer, thankgs again

Answer (score -1):

First things first. There are no loops in your code.

If you're coming from PHP, then I would guess Javascript's asynchronous execution model looks alien to you. I would suggest learning more about Javascript.

Learn the following in the following order:

1. Callbacks
2. Promises
3. Generators
4. Async/Await

Those are the different approaches on how to handle Javascript's asynchronous execution model starting from the most basic (callbacks) to the most modern approach, "async/await".

Async/await would be the most readable but it would be better if you understand how async/await came to be since they are easy to use the wrong way if you don't understand what you're doing.

Comment: Generators *before* promises? Interesting suggestion.

Comment: While I agree that generators are an important advanced topic in JavaScript, I don't really see how they fit in to the issue at hand here. Could you elaborate why you mention those?

Comment: It's not so much callbacks to learn as it is asynchronous operations and async callbacks.  Callbacks used with `array.map()` are no big deal and easy to understand.  And, I'd agree that most people will want to learn and use promises long before generators.  Plus, I'm really not sure how all this is entirely relevant to what the OP asked.

Comment: please read the update in my question, the code is not mine, i'm just try understand the code and looking for to update to es7, callback and promises make me crazy

Comment: @DDave: `async` functions return promises. `async/await` is syntactic sugar for promises, so you should at least understand those.

Comment: My point was that the OP needs to understand those concepts before going further. The other answers are better, I admit. And they make more sense for those already familiar with Javascript. For a Javascript beginner though, an understanding of the JS's asynchronous execution model is essential in understanding the better answers.