# How to solve the pyramid of doom with async/await?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I want to know how to avoid the pyramid of doom of this code:

**Original code**

```
var PlayerService = {
    getPlayerTeamId: function(playerId, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/player/" + playerId + "/team",
            success: function(team) {
                callback(team.id)
            }
        });
    },
    getPlayers: function(teamId, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/team/" + teamId + "/player",
            success: callback
        });
    }
};

var PlayerDetailsController = {
    playerId: 8,
    showTeammatesClick: function() {
        PlayerService.getPlayerTeamId(this.playerId, function(teamId) {
            PlayerService.getPlayers(teamId, function(playerList) {
                // Render playerList
            });
        });
    }
};
```

and this is my version with async/await to avoid sol that pyramid:
**My version**

```
var PlayerService = {
    getPlayerTeamId: async function(playerId, callback) {
        return await $.ajax({
                   url: "/player/" + playerId + "/team",
                   success: function(team) {
                       callback(team.id)
                   }
               });
    },
    getPlayers: async function(teamId, callback) {
        return await $.ajax({
                   url: "/team/" + teamId + "/player",
                   success: callback
               });
    }
};

var PlayerDetailsController = {
    playerId: 8,
    showTeammatesClick: function() {
        PlayerService.getPlayerTeamId(this.playerId, function(teamId) {
            PlayerService.getPlayers(teamId, function(playerList) {
                // Render playerList
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Is it OK ? or how can I use this async/await correctly? I'm trying that "getPlayerTeamId" and "getPlayers" should not expect the callback parameter, and avoid callback in any way.

any advise ? Thanks and have a good day :D

Comment: There are a few questions about this on the site, including [Node.js, the pyramid of doom (even with async), can you write it better?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25575837) and [avoid multiple returns looped in javascript - async / await to solve callback pyramid or callback hell,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46167078). Do either of those answer your question?

Answer (score 5):

The pyramid of doom is not solved from placing `async`/`await` somewhere, but from returning and chaining promises *instead of accepting callbacks*. Notice that your service methods don't even need to be `async` when they just can return a promise - in any case [don't use `return await`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43985067/1048572):

```
const PlayerService = {
    getPlayerTeamId(playerId ) {
//                          ^ no callback
        return $.ajax({
//      ^^^^^^ the promise
            url: "/player/" + playerId + "/team"
        }).then(team => team.id);
    },
    // same here
    getPlayers(teamId) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: "/team/" + teamId + "/player"
        });
    }
};
```

Now that the [promisification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) is done, we can start using promise `.then()` or `await` syntax instead of nesting callbacks when calling these methods:

```
const PlayerDetailsController = {
    playerId: 8,
    async showTeammatesClick() {
        const teamId = await PlayerService.getPlayerTeamId(this.playerId);
        const playerList = await PlayerService.getPlayers(teamId);
        … // Render playerList
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that if you are using async/await, your codebase is in ES6.

So you can actually just use [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to replace the `$.ajax({...})` syntax:

```
var PlayerService = {
    getPlayerTeamId: function(playerId) {
        return fetch(`/player/${playerId}/team`);
    },
    getPlayers: function(teamId) {
        return fetch(`/team/${teamId}/player`);
    }
};

var PlayerDetailsController = {
    playerId: 8,
    showTeammatesClick: async function() {
        const teamId = await PlayerService.getPlayerTeamId(this.playerId);
        const playerList = await PlayerService.getPlayers(teamId);

        /* Render playerList here */
    }
};
```

The point of using async/await or Promises is to avoid callbacks, which solves the "pyramid of doom".

So when building your `PlayerService` functions, you can skip the `callback` parameter altogether.

Alternatively, you can also just use plain [Promise syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises):

```
var PlayerService = {
    getPlayerTeamId: function(playerId) {
        return fetch(`/player/${playerId}/team`);
    },
    getPlayers: function(teamId) {
        return fetch(`/team/${teamId}/player`);
    }
};

var PlayerDetailsController = {
    playerId: 8,
    showTeammatesClick: function() {
        PlayerService.getPlayerTeamId(this.playerId)
          .then(PlayerService.getPlayers)
          .then(playerList => {
              /* Render playerList here */
          });
    }
};
```